# Omega override simple-layout.tpl.php for content types

Tags: 7, theming

I have copied the simple-layout files and customized, the custom layout is simply mats2015.simple-layout (`mats2015.simple-layout.tpl.php`). I need to override this file for a specific content type (`plain-page`).

Before Omega 4 (and using the layouts extension) I would use the following:

- In `theme_alpha_preprocess_html()`: `$variables['theme_hook_suggestions'] = array('html__plain_page_wrapper');`
- In `theme_alpha_preprocess_page()`: `$variables['theme_hook_suggestions'] = array('html__plain_page')`;

And, together, those two template files (`html_plain_page_wrapper.tpl.php`, `html__plain_page.tpl.php`) would simply render `$page['content']` and nothing else.

If, within `mats2015.simple-layout.tpl.php` I include `get_defined_vars()` I see this:

```
'omega_layout' => 
array (size=7)
  'name' => string 'mats2015.simple' (length=15)
  'path' => string 'sites/all/themes/mats2015/layouts/mats2015.simple' (length=49)
  'file' => string 'sites/all/themes/mats2015/layouts/mats2015.simple/mats2015.simple.layout.inc' (length=76)
  'info' => 
    array (size=4)
      'name' => string 'MATS 2015 Simple' (length=16)
      'description' => string 'preview = preview.png' (length=21)
      'template' => string 'mats2015.simple-layout' (length=22)
      'regions' => 
        array (size=11)
          ...
  'theme' => string 'mats2015' (length=8)
  'attached' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'template' => string 'mats2015.simple-layout' (length=22)
  'theme_hook_suggestions' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
```

So, the question is: is there a preprocess hook I'm missing that I can use to switch from `mats2015.simple.tpl.php` to `some-other.tpl.php` based on content type? Or is there a naming convention for the layout extension files that I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, I was able to accomplish this using the following:

tl;dr: Create another layout extension, and use `theme_omega_layout_alter(&$layout)` to switch.  That's the preprocess function I had to track down.

*(assuming use of included layout *simple-layout* and you want to create a layout for node type plain-page [the naming convention doesn't matter])*

1. Copy `themes/_your-theme_/layouts/simple` to `themes/_your-theme_/layouts/plain`.
2. Modify the file names:

   - simple.layout.inc -> plain.layout.inc
   - simple-layout.tpl.php -> plain-layout.tpl.php
3. Modify `plain.layout.inc` (It's just like a `.info` file for a theme, self-explanatory)
4. Modify `plain-layout.tpl.php` to suit your needs (In my case, I need to remove everything except `render($page['content'])`.
5. Open `themes/_your-theme_/template.php` and add `theme_omega_layout_alter(&$layout)`:

   ```
   // this is specific to my use case
   // change 'theme' to your theme name, as you would with any
   // preprocess function
   function theme_omega_layout_alter(&$layout) {
     $cPath = current_path();
     if (strpos($cPath, 'invite-print') !== 0) {
       $layout = 'plain';
     }
   }
   ```

*The following is only necessary if you want to change parent structure (`<html>`, `<head>`, etc.), which I needed to*

1. Open `themes/_your-theme_/preprocess/html.preprocess.inc` and put this in:

   ```
    // this is specific to my use case
    // change 'theme' to your theme name, as you would with any
    // preprocess function
    function theme_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
      $cPath = current_path();
      if (strpos($cPath, 'invite-print') !== 0) {
        $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'html__plain_page';
      }
    }
   ```
2. Create `/themes/_your-theme_/templates/html--plain-page.tpl.php` and modify as necessary.

It felt like overkill for my situation (having to create entire new layouts) but I understand why it was done - it's crazy powerful for sites that need to make drastically different layouts for different pages.  Think different regions, stylesheets, js, etc - completely different .info files, essentially.

Hope this helps someone!