# Change Omega4 Layout Based on Content Type via template.php

Tags: nodes, theming

I want to set Omega4 Layout defaults based on Content Type. I am trying to use the following code, but the hook_omega_layout_alter doesn't seem to use the $node variable. What am I missing?

I have already referenced [Omega override simple-layout.tpl.php for content types](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/123117/omega-override-simple-layout-tpl-php-for-content-types) but, once I try and and a switch statement based of $node->type it stops working.

What can I do to set the default Omega4 Layout based on Content Type using the hook_omega_layout_alter function?

```
function THEME_omega_layout_alter(&$vars, &$layout) {
  $node = $vars['node'];
  switch ($node->type) {
    case "article":
        $layout = 'article';
        break;
    case "blog":
        $layout = 'blog';
        break;
    case "market":
        $layout = 'market';
        break;
    case "merchant":
        $layout = 'merchant';
        break;
    case "product":
        $layout = 'product';
        break;
    case "update":
        $layout = 'update';
        break;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per referenced question I would go with something like the following:

```
function THEMENAME_omega_layout_alter(&$layout) {
  if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))
      && $node = node_load(arg(1))) {
        switch ($node->type) {
          case 'article':
            $layout = 'article';
            break;
          case 'blog':
            $layout = 'blog';
            break;
          default:
            $layout = 'default';
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So this works for me...

```
function THEME_omega_layout_alter(&$layout) {

  $default = 'basic';

  $layout = $default;

  if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
    $nid = arg(1);
    $node = node_load($nid);
    if (isset($node) && $node->type == 'page') {
      $layout = 'basic';
    }
    if (isset($node) && ($node->type == 'project_page' || $node->type == 'project_front')) {
      $layout = 'full-page';
    }
  }
}
```

Hope that helps someone.
I personally think it is overkill to have to create new layouts in omega 4 to create minor changes... but hey, it is a quick and simple process!