# How to change head title of a page having a Omega 4 subtheme?

Tags: theming

I'm trying to implement this: http://ryanissamson.drupalgardens.com/blog/html-node-and-view-title to add the possibility of having HTML injected in node titles. It works great for the node titles in the pages and the views.

But there's something I cannot accomplish: the "$head_title" part. I can't change the text of the title showed in the browser tab, so, assuming that I have a mid-italic title like "Ti*tle*", in the browser tab it shows something like "Ti[i]tle[/i]".

I think it's because Omega 4 uses the Layout system, that works perfect, and we don't have to override page.tpl.php, as seen in [How do you override page.tpl.php in Omega 4?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/78632/how-do-you-override-page-tpl-php-in-omega-4)

Here people say to this guy to disable Layouts, but for me that's not an option at this moment.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Changing head title for a page in Omega 4 based on node id - same approach will work for any other content. (code below goes into template.php)

Didn't test if this method supports described above HTML injection.

```
    function yourtheme_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
        if ($node){
        $mynodeid = $node->nid;
// this will set "Custom Title" for a node with NID = 10
        if($mynodeid == 10) {
            $variables['head_title'] = t('Custom Title');
        }
      }
    }
```