# Why isn't my page--front.tpl.php for my sub-theme used?

Tags: 7, theming

I created a sub theme under Omega, and I created the page--front.tpl.php template in mytheme/templates for the front page, but It's not working.

Can anyone tell me how to create a front page template in Omega?

Comment: Did you clear/flush the cache? Did you enable the omega sub theme?

Comment: Yes I did...But still not working.I think the problem is omega.I also implemented the hook_preprocess_page and no luck so far.

Comment: You can use module https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_themer to debug. With devel_themer module you can see your front page use template, function preprocess, process.

Comment: what is the version of omega?

Comment: we used omega 4 theme

Comment: @elan Check the answer to [this](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/78632/how-do-you-override-page-tpl-php-in-omega-4) question. I think that is what you're up against.